# Oracle Database Trigger Selecting Previous Row

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am writing an AFTER INSERT Trigger on a table which is getting data from an Excel file, which has these three columns:

```
Tag_No ,Date ,Problem
```

The problem is that in this Excel File the `Tag_No` is not repeated when it is the same as the previous one. An example of this data is as follows:

```
   Tag_No ,Date           ,Problem
     1     17-JUL-14       ABCS
           18-JUL-14       asdf
     2     17-JUL-14       ABCS
           18-JUL-14       asdf
```

`Tag_No` will be empty if it is repeating like above. I would like to copy the above `Tag_No` for each row which I am inserting.

Comment: Is there no opportunity to step in between the excel file being handed to you and trying to insert it into the database? This is the kind of thing that is easily solved in Excel (via e.g. a macro) where columns and rows **have** a defined order. In SQL, rows aren't meant to have any inherent "order".

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest solving this in a different way.  Add an auto-incrementing column to the table.  This will keep track of the order that the rows are put into the table.  You can do this by defining a sequence and then using the sequence in the trigger.

Then, after the table is in the database, you can run an update to do what you want:

```
update table t
    set tag = (select max(tag) keep (dense_rank first order by id desc)
               from table t2
               where t2.id < t.id and tag is not null
              )
    where tag is null;
```

Comment: I am Loading Data Into Table using a External API from excel File I just Have to Handle this In trigger when its Is Being Inserted